# Custom files in your own package

Tags: r, package

Using RStudio I am trying to create my own R package. The main task of the package will be the import and visualization of data from an unusual file system. The main function reads and appropriately processes all files from the directory given as a parameter, returning the appropriate data frame. I would like the package to contain a directory with some sample files in it so that all the examples in the @examples section work correctly.
How can I include such a sample directory with the appropriate files in the package being created.

Comment: Have a look at https://r-pkgs.org/data.html#data.

Comment: The `./inst/` directory is where you should put files that you want available with the package (but not loaded as source code, data, or help pages). See https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages, perhaps `./inst/extdata/`.

Comment: It was indeed the point! This is also the solution to my problem. In addition, I noticed that I can add not only files to the `./inst/` directory, but also my own directory with files, which for me is the best and the solution I am looking for.